# ERROR: @nebular/theme has no exported member NbAutocompleteModule

Tags: angular, typescript, nebular, ngx-admin

I am using nebular theme latest version 4.6.0. All other modules are working fine, however while using **NbAutocompleteModule**, it gives me following error:

`**ERROR: @nebular/theme has no exported member NbAutocompleteModule**`

I have included this module in app.module.ts file:

```
import {
  NbAutocompleteModule,
} from '@nebular/theme';
```

also included it in the imports section of @NgModule like:

```
imports: [NbAutocompleteModule]
```

Has anyone faced the same issue.

Comment: From where you refered this `NbAutocompleteModule` module? https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/components-overview make sure you have correct or latest version installed!

Comment: I was using the latest version 4.6.0, however this module is available in the next beta version 5.0.0-beta.1. Thank you very much @PrashantPimpale

Comment: You are always welcome!